# Un-Publish a Function

Tags: palantir-foundry

I created a function in Functions and published it with the tag `0.1.0`.

After doing some refactoring I decided to rename the function and release it with the tag `1.0.0`.

Is there a way that I can get rid of or un-publish the original function to avoid pollution of the namespace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 ways to go about this:

1. Foundry supports deleting the entire Function with all its previous published versions. In your case, this should work since you renamed your function so now it's considered a separate Function. However, this is not recommended in case some modules can still be using your previous version
2. You can hide unused functions from search. This doesn't delete them and they can still be used by other modules, but they should stop polluting your user interface.

Both can be achieved from your repository, when you select your Function in the Functions tab at the bottom and click on the cogwheel in the top right corner of the tab. You should see "Delete function" button and "Hide function" toggle.

Comment: thank you, I completetly overlooked the cogwheel.

Comment: Is this achievable on a per-tag/per-version basis or hiding will affect the function overall?