# How to unregister functions

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-functions

Is there a way to unregister TypeScript functions?
We have a lot of functions that are not used (and should not be used anymore). Their presence can be confusing/missleading for users. We would like to remove them from available functions in Workshop, Actions, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function repository, at the bottom in the "functions" tab, you should see the list of published function and you can delete any version there.
[image]

Additional alternatives: [Un-Publish a Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71280427/un-publish-a-function)